Putting points on map using ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to create a map that shows a shaded region and a bunch of labeled dots of landmarks in the area. For example, I want to have a map of New York City with Manhattan shaded and then a dot where Times Square is with a label that says "Times Square" and a dot where Central Park is with a label that says "Central Park" and so on for different landmarks. (And of course I'm not actually trying to map NYC; this is just an example I'm using to illustrate the idea.)
So what I've done is create a new map project in ArcGIS Pro. And I've gotten the shaded region to show on the map because someone sent me the appropriate shapefile and I added it as a layer in my contents menu. What I am struggling to do is to plot the different landmark points on the map and add labels.
To me, it seems like the problem is that if someone has already created data, I can put it into my project and then manipulate it. But what I don't know what to do is create the underlying data to be put into my project.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Using Google Earth to create a KML file with the landmarks, and then adding that KML file to my ArcGIS project. The problem with this is that the points and the labels appear huge, and the only icon seems to be the big yellow thumb tack. Visually, this is not going to work for my purposes. And I don't see any way to change the symbology. Going one step further, I tried to use the KML to Layer tool to convert this into something I could more easily work with. The problem is that when I run the tool, it completes but gives the warning "WARNING 000401: No features were found for processing" This doesn't make sense to me because I see all the features as yellow thumb tacks so I don't understand why they can't be found.
Create a spreadsheet with names and street addresses, and then use the "Address and Place Layer" under "Add Data" to plot the points on my map. I couldn't get this to work because it's asking me for a locator which I don't think I have.
Try to play around with ArcGIS Online to see if I can do my project there instead of on ArcGIS Pro. I'm not sure if it's my account or something else, but my ArcGIS Online seems to be very stripped down compared to my ArcGIS Pro. For example, I couldn't figure out how to upload the shapefile I needed to display my shaded region.

I am really not sure what to do here.

This is probably going to get closed. I'd have a look at the ESRI resources - https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-pro/resources

The standard way is to create a featureclass (the dataset) and then edit that featureclass to add your points https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/create-points-on-a-map.htm

You best bet would be to create a CSV with the Name of your Point (Label), Latitude and Longitude. You can do this in Excel and then save to csv.
Add that CSV to ArcGIS Pro. It will be added to the Table of Context as a "Stand-alone Table". Right-click the added csv and select the "Display XY Data" option.
In the dialog, choose the X and Y coordinates in the relavant fields and then hit ok.
This will add a layer to the map you can style and add labels to.
ESRI documentation will be able to assist from here.
